# What is this ??? Glyph I found?

Tags: god-of-war-ragnarok

In the new Valhalla DLC, I collected a Perfect Glyph simply called **???** . The description states "Memories of the collector are sealed within..."

Once I finished my run and returned to the Black Sands, nothing seemed different. The run ended as normal, nothing unusual. What's the deal with this Glyph?

Comment: Any chance you can upload a screenshot?

Comment: I'd have to rerun to find it, I ended my run without thinking about screenshotting it :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Reddit and other sources:

> To unlock its true ability, simply navigate to the menu and hold Square to destroy it. Now every time your equipped relic charges diminish, it will automatically equip a random new one for you. This allows you to never run out of relics.

It should be an easter egg as it was for Forbidden West.

Comment: Oh huh. So the game never explicitly tells you what it does, it's just an observable effect after destroying it? Weird!